Object Counting Across Frames in YOLOv5 Video Detection
I'm working on an object detection project using YOLOv5 in Python, where I need to detect and count bicycles and motorcycles in a video as they cross a vertical line in the middle of the frame. However, I’m facing an issue where the objects are being counted in every frame, leading to inflated counts.
In my code, I track each object using a unique object_id that’s generated based on the object’s class and position. Despite this, the detection seems to reset in each frame, and the objects get counted multiple times.
Here’s a snippet of the code (the full version is below):

import torch
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the YOLOv5 model (we are using the small version, yolov5s)
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')

# Load the video
video_path = 'C:/Users/komyj/Downloads/yolov5-master/yolov5-master/data/images/test_2.mp4'
output_path = 'C:/Users/komyj/Downloads/yolov5-master/yolov5-master/data/images/output.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error opening the video.")
    exit()

# Get video dimensions
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
line_position = frame_width // 2  # Vertical line in the middle of the video

# Initialize counters
count_bikes = 0
count_motorcycles = 0

# Dictionary to store tracked objects with their ID and position history
tracked_objects = {}

# Function to check if an object has crossed the line
def is_object_passing(line_position, current_x, previous_x):
    return previous_x < line_position and current_x >= line_position

# Setup VideoWriter to save the output video
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

if not out.isOpened():
    print("Error opening VideoWriter.")
    cap.release()
    exit()

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Convert the image to RGB (OpenCV uses BGR)
    img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    
    # Object detection
    results = model(img_rgb)
    
    # Render the detection results
    img_rendered = results.render()[0]
    
    # Convert back to BGR for OpenCV
    img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img_rendered, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    
    # Display the vertical line
    cv2.line(img_bgr, (line_position, 0), (line_position, frame_height), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    # Process detected objects
    for detection in results.pred[0]:
        x1, y1, x2, y2, conf, class_id = detection
        center_x = int((x1 + x2) / 2)
        center_y = int((y1 + y2) / 2)

        # Generate a unique ID for each object based on its class and position
        object_id = f"{int(class_id)}-{int(x1)}-{int(y1)}"

        # If the object is already being tracked, update its position
        if object_id in tracked_objects:
            prev_center_x = tracked_objects[object_id]['center_x']
            tracked_objects[object_id]['center_x'] = center_x
        else:
            # If the object is not being tracked, add it with its ID and initial position
            tracked_objects[object_id] = {'class_id': class_id, 'center_x': center_x, 'counted': False}

        # Check if the object has already been counted and if it has crossed the line
        if not tracked_objects[object_id]['counted'] and is_object_passing(line_position, center_x, prev_center_x):
            if class_id == 1:  # ID for a bicycle
                count_bikes += 1
            elif class_id == 3:  # ID for a motorcycle
                count_motorcycles += 1
            tracked_objects[object_id]['counted'] = True  # Mark the object as counted

        # Draw a rectangle around the detected object
        if class_id == 1:  # ID for a bicycle
            cv2.rectangle(img_bgr, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(img_bgr, "Bike", (int(x1), int(y1) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        
        elif class_id == 3:  # ID for a motorcycle
            cv2.rectangle(img_bgr, (int(x1), int(y1)), (int(x2), int(y2)), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(img_bgr, "Motorcycle", (int(x1), int(y1) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # Display the bike and motorcycle counts
    cv2.putText(img_bgr, f'Bikes Count: {count_bikes}', (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(img_bgr, f'Motorcycles Count: {count_motorcycles}', (50, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    
    # Save the frame to the new video
    out.write(img_bgr)

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Print the final results
print(f'Final Bike Count: {count_bikes}')
print(f'Final Motorcycle Count: {count_motorcycles}')

Here’s a summary of what I’ve tried:

I track the objects using a dictionary (tracked_objects) to store their object_id, position (center_x), and a counted flag.

I check if an object has crossed the line using its current and previous positions.

I only increment the count when an object crosses the line from left to right and hasn’t been counted yet.



it's always the same approach: tracking, then count crossings with hysteresis. from what you say, it sounds like your code fails to associate detections to existing tracks. you should refactor your code and bring out this structure. right now, the code mixes everything together. look at object_id = ... and think about what you're assigning there. -- I really hope nobody takes this as cheap reputation points and ruins the teaching moment. this is for OP to debug. this is a mere matter of more practice with general programming.

Where do you set counted to true? I can only see that it is initially false in your else statement.

Also, maybe try to visualize your logic with a diagram, this usually helps in identifiying logical mistakes
